# Convert Stream object to json object and then to user defined object

Tags: c#, json

I call a service function which returns me a stream.

The stream contains an JSON object with two properties (Url and Status).

I want want to convert this JSON object into my user defined class called 'Response'. Response class has two properties Url and Status.

The code I have so far, but unclear what to do next or if I need to implement something else:

```
var response = _service.GetObject("Create");
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); 
var jsonObject = serializer.DeserializeObject(response.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overload which takes a `T` generic type parameter and internally casts to the desired type:

```
Response jsonObject = serializer.DeserializeObject<Response>(response.ReadToEnd());
```

Note [`JavaScriptSerializer` is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx). You should use [`Json.NET`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to work with JSON, which has the equivalent:

```
var response = _service.GetObject("Create");
var serializer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Brill, first line didnt work, as you mentioned it is deprecated, the second implementation worked for me. Many thanks!