# Grabbing Json Data to String in Gridview

Tags: c#, json

I'm setting up a website ASPX file that grabs the weather for the next 3 days, the output is in JSON and their classes are too complicated for me to understand it. If I want to extract just the weather for the next 3 days how do I go on about doing that?

https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

This is the JSON output displayed on top.

`What I'm trying to accomplish is to extract the next 3 days of the weather "Description" and put it to a GridView.` I have used a JSON beautifier to get the classes but I am still confused.

Any help would be appreciated

This is my current code and I'm stuck here

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchTerm = TextBox1.Text;

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + Server.UrlEncode(searchTerm) + "&units=metric&APPID=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");

        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {

            Label1.Text = "The Next 3 days of weather in your area in" + searchTerm + " .";
            JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string resString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            });

            GridView1.DataSource = ?;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
            Label.Text = "Invalid Response";
    }

 public class Main
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }
        public double temp_min { get; set; }
        public double temp_max { get; set; }
        public double pressure { get; set; }
        public double sea_level { get; set; }
        public double grnd_level { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public double temp_kf { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string main { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clouds
    {
        public int all { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wind
    {
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public double deg { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sys
    {
        public string pod { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rain
    {
        public double __invalid_name__3h { get; 

set; }
    }

    public class Snow
    {
        public double __invalid_name__3h { get; 

set; }
    }

    public class List
    {
        public int dt { get; set; }
        public Main main { get; set; }
        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public Sys sys { get; set; }
        public string dt_txt { get; set; }
        public Rain rain { get; set; }
        public Snow snow { get; set; }
    }

    public class Coord
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lon { get; set; }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Coord coord { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string cod { get; set; }
        public double message { get; set; }
        public int cnt { get; set; }
        public List<List> list { get; set; }
        public City city { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: use json2csharp website to generate classes from json? Or use https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: @LeszekRepie Hi Leszek I used <http://json2csharp.com/> to create and generate the classes but everything is so nested and complicated to me.

Comment: just deserialize and use  var deserialziedDAta = Json....(jsonCOntent). var threeDays = deserialziedDAta.List.Take(3); threeDays is a list of weathers. Then for each...

Comment: @LeszekRepie I have added in my incomplete code can you show me how it is done? I am currently stuck at that point

Comment: @SalemWitchez3 post your json data also

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj I have updated it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Stream object to json object and then to user defined object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940536/convert-stream-object-to-json-object-and-then-to-user-defined-object)

Comment: @SalemWitchez3 Please check the answer.let me know if you have any questions